# How to break a string into two arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

Is there a way to extract the strings removed by `String#split` into a separate array?

```
s = "This is a simple, uncomplicated sentence."
a = s.split( /,|\./ )  #=> [ "This is a simple", "uncomplicated sentence" ]
x = ... => should contain [ ",", "." ]
```

Note that the actual regex I need to use is much more complex than this example.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't work that way (unescaped dot).

Comment: You mention x in your code comment , where is X?

Comment: x is something I want to calculate - I need some way of getting both a and x from s.

Comment: I thought you were looking for a method that returns both, the matched delimiters *and* the substrings in between.

Comment: @Stefan well, with the answer given, I can just define a function which returns a,x and I am done - that's close enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
a = s.scan( /,|\./ )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want both the matched delimiters and the substrings in between as in Stefan's comment, then you should use `split` with captures.

```
"This is a simple, uncomplicated sentence."
.split(/([,.])/)
# => ["This is a simple", ",", " uncomplicated sentence", "."]
```

If you want to separate them into different arrays, then do:

```
a, x =
"This is a simple, uncomplicated sentence."
.split(/([,.])/).each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
a # => ["This is a simple", " uncomplicated sentence"]
x # => [",", "."]
```

or

```
a =
"This is a simple, uncomplicated sentence."
.split(/([,.])/)
a.select.with_index{|_, i| i.even?}
# => ["This is a simple", " uncomplicated sentence"]
a.select.with_index{|_, i| i.odd?}
# => [",", "."]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = s.split(/,/)[1..-1]
```